# passing data with redirect in codiegniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a books website that i want the user when choose to buy a certain book redirect to the **thanks** page , the **thanks** page will contain a recommendation for the books ( like the same category of the book chosen )

briefly what i want here to pass the data from the database in flash session

but i get the following error

> Fatal error: main() [function.main]: The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "CI_DB_mysql_result" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in /home/content/27/10962827/html/beta/application/views/thanks.php on line

I have a controller like the following

```
// get the same category books 
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('category');
            $this->db->where('category.id', $page_details->row()->category_id);
            $this->db->join('books', 'books.category_id = category.id');
            $this->db->limit(4, random_string('numeric', 1));
            $categories = $this->db->get();

            $this->session->set_flashdata('categories', $categories);

            redirect('order/thanks', 'refresh');


public function thanks()
{
    $categories = $this->session->flashdata('categories');

    $this->load->view('control_front', array('page' => 'thanks', 'categories ' => $categories ));       

}
```

And here is the view

```
<div class="recommended">

                <?php if($categories->num_rows() > 1): ?>
                    <h3>كتب مقترحة :</h3>
                    <?php foreach($categories->result() as $cat): ?>
                    <div class="single-recomm">

                        <a href="<?php echo site_url( 'book/'.$cat->id ) ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo site_url() . 'uploads/' . $cat->uploaded_image ?>">                                
                            <p><?php echo $cat->name .' '. $cat->sname ?></p>
                        </a>        

                    </div> <!-- end single-recomm -->
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div> <!-- end recommended -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you called the `$this->db->get();` then there is no reason  to use the or to fetch again the data in view you are doing wrong in the `foreach loop`  there is no sense to use the `$categories->result()` you already fetched the data by using `get` and in `$categories` you have the information so just loop through it, therefore you are getting this error because you don't have the required objects in `$categories` to call the `result()` function

And also its a bad practice to run the queries in the controller , all your business logics and database handling should be done in the `models`

```
<div class="recommended">

                <?php if(!empty($categories)): ?>
                    <h3>كتب مقترحة :</h3>
                    <?php foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
                    <div class="single-recomm">

                        <a href="<?php echo site_url( 'book/'.$cat->id ) ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo site_url() . 'uploads/' . $cat->uploaded_image ?>">                                
                            <p><?php echo $cat->name .' '. $cat->sname ?></p>
                        </a>        

                    </div> <!-- end single-recomm -->
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div> <!-- end recommended -->
```

You have already passed the data to the thanks view just loop through the `$categories`

```
public function thanks()
{
    $categories = $this->session->flashdata('categories');

    $this->load->view('control_front', array('page' => 'thanks', 'categories ' => $categories ));       

}
```

Comment: so how can i get to pass the data to thanks page , by the session

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good way to pass data through session because of security and also loading
you can pass categories with redirect like this:

```
       //$this->db->select('t1.id');
       // $this->db->from('category AS t1');
       // $this->db->where('t1.id', $page_details->row()->category_id);
       // $this->db->join('books', 'books.category_id = t1.id');
       // $this->db->limit(4, random_string('numeric', 1));
       // $categories = $this->db->get();

        //$this->session->set_flashdata('categories', $categories);

        redirect('order/thanks/'.$page_details->row()->category_id.'', 'refresh');
```

and inside your thanks function get your records according this category_id and pass it to view

Answer (score 0):

My solution.
Build controler tanks.php

Then in index() function load your data.

And

In submited function of buy proccesing

You can redirect to tanks.php controller.

I hope clearly.